# Finding the selling price of FTR (energy trading)

Tags: trading

I have been reading the forum here for a while but this is my first question. I am trying to figure out (for an assignment) the price some FTRs (Financial Transmission Rights) were sold. Here is an example of the data I have. I am supposed to figure out the price that these FTRs were sold. I feel that some information is missing. Any good reference on the subject?

[image: The data that I have]

Can one of you help me to figure out the price these FTRs? What formulas would you use?

Thanks,

David

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not quant question